# Pandas aggregate with condition. Join if empty, first is not empty

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
id       rq_id          method  user_id     error   reservation_id  code
0       609d444a9d34a   reservation 3261    False   82122        
1       609d444a9d34a                       False   82122           346346
2279    60c6ff0c63e45   reservation 5231    False   92902       
2280    60c6ff0c63e45               5231    False   92902           415643
```

There supposed to be 2 rows for each rq_id. I want to aggregate these two rows into one.
Problem I have is with the user_id column, because in some of the rows it exists only in one of the rq_id, but some of the rows it exists in both.

Current code:

```
clean_df = clean_df.groupby('rq_id').agg({
    'rq_id':'first',
    'method':"".join,
    'user_id':'first',   # <=== here what do I do?
    'ucode':"".join,
    'reservation_id':'first',
    'dt':'first'
})
```

Expected:

```
id       rq_id          method  user_id     error   reservation_id  code
0       609d444a9d34a   reservation 3261    False   82122           346346
1       60c6ff0c63e45   reservation 5231    False   92902           415643
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: `Problem I have is with the user_id column, because in some of the rows it exists only in one of the rq_id, but some of the rows it exists in both.` - Not understand, if use `first` it not working? It should be.

Comment: It doesn't work if `first` is empty. If `first` is empty, then I need `second`

Comment: Did you try `np.logical_or.reduce` there instead of `first`?

Comment: No I didn't. I was looking for something like that, but not sure how to use it. Looks interesting, maybe it can solve the issue as well. Anyway, already solved by the solution suggested by @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need repalce first empty strings to missing values, so `first` return first non `NaN` value.

```
clean_df = clean_df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('rq_id').first()
```

Comment: Interesting. I am trying, and I am getting an error: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: @justadev - If use `first` only and not `.join` ?

Comment: I think the error was on another column. I did the np.nan trick on just the user_id column, and it worked. Thanks!